# Redirect url link based on login user using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

How to create url link based on user name(gmail). 
Eg: http://www.test.com/%username%

The following code more or less suitable for me. Only i want to know how to get username automatically on the input area.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(){
        var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
        lnk.href = "http://www.test.com" + userInput;
        lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
    }
    </script>
    Link : <a href="" id=lnk>nothing here yet</a> <br>
    <input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter username' />
    <input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Link'/>
```

Here also same issue

```
<a id="reflectedlink" href="http://www.google.com/search">http://www.test.com/</a>
<input id="username"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var link= document.getElementById('reflectedlink');
    var input= document.getElementById('username');
    input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {
        link.search= '/'+encodeURIComponent(input.value);
        link.firstChild.data= link.href;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem mate..??

Comment: I have created multiple user page based on their name my website . And i want to link only particular page for the user.  for example if aaa logged in i want to link www.test.com/aaa. In a link subpage should be change based on the user name

Comment: Its not clear what ur question is mate.The subject is to redirect and the content specifies you need to get username automatically on the input area..Please specify your exact need

Comment: The given code does not solve my issue. After many search and try im choosing it for by pass way. I need to create link+%username%. PHP not support here only html and java will support.

Comment: there are 2 sets of code.In which does your problem lie..??

Comment: Both codes are similar output are same. Is there any possible to get username automically into the place of enter value in both codes. And how to remove "?" in 2nd code

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand what your requirement was.But check the below fiddle if this was what you really meant.

```
Link : <a href="" id="lnk">nothing here yet</a> <br>
    <input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter username' />
    <input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Link'/>
<script>
function changeText(){
        var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "http://www.test.com/" + userInput;
        lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
    }
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uxcce7h4/)

```
var link= document.getElementById('reflectedlink');
var input= document.getElementById('username');
input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {
    link.pathname= "/"+input.value;
    link.firstChild.data= link.href;
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1cktrvmx/)

Comment: Yea, thanks for 2nd code. Almost over! Is there any option to get username(get gmail id) from login Instead of enter input?

Comment: Yes, Eg. I have logged in name as "useraaa@gmail.com". Now we typing in the input area "useraaa'. Instead of typing the name can we get the same from user login. Not only user name any other specification to the specific user.

Comment: It depends on what u have in the specified page.

Comment: Sorry im not get you. How to get username(currently logged on to the browser)?

Comment: what server-side script are you using..??php ,java..??

Comment: google sites, and also have option to squarespace. Its not easy to use php in google sites:(

Comment: do u have a username in the url.??

Comment: Yes, i have created page name with username. Its not a problem. We can change page name whatever we want

Comment: I think this is alert. rite? Anyway how to get only user name into the input area?

Comment: Thanks for ur support, and im sorry its not solved my issue. Its just giving after".com/". And im also scared I cnt use http://jsfiddle.net/1cktrvmx/ I have tried https://sites.google.com/a/domain.com, after run and enter it will show only https://sites.google.com/"input". /a/domain.com cnt get from there. pls help

Comment: Seriously I really can't solve the issue all by myself.Try researching mate.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting the user to his own page:

`window.location.href = "http://test.com/"+$('#userInput').value;`

Comment: Sry, Im not developer. Where to use this line?

Comment: well where do you get the username from? Does the user type it in the input field or you want to get it any other way?

Comment: google account login from the browser. And i have full list of user name and email id, if u want we can use it the way

Comment: Then substitute `$('#userInput').value` in the code above with the username value from the list and use that code to redirect the user - for example right after a successful login